# Using azure app service deployment slots to run different apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

Deployment slots on azure app service are really intended to run new versions of same app for blue/green deploy strategies. The question I have is it against the rules to run an app with multiple components (front end/back end) to put them into different deployment. On Standard plan, I can load up to 5 services into a single azure app service plan. This would be great as cost saving measure in non prod environments where a single instance of each service is just fine. The question I have is
a) is this against the rules?
b) are there any pitfalls with this strategy?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can host as many web apps on your app service plan as you want. You just have to ensure they don't consume to much CPU or memory. So I wouldn't use deployment slots.

Comment: Agree with the above, for web apps, you pay for the App Service plan so no real limit to the number of web sites you deploy under it.  The limits are CPU and storage which you can find here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/app-service/plans//

Comment: I don't think my question was clear. When I said plan, I meant a single app service instance of a particular plan type (in this case standard). A single service instance comes with 5 deployment slots. To my knowledge, it's not possible to stack multiple apps on a single app service instance without going the docker route.

Comment: What do you mean with app service instance of a plan type? An App service plan is just a logical container which can hosts as many app service instances (API App, Web App, etc...) as you want. You just have to ensure they don't consume to much memory. The App service plan just defines the available CPU and memory.